# How to concatenate strings in getting value from resource bundle in Jasper Report?

Tags: internationalization, jasper-reports

I want to get task names from resource bundle in my report. I try to concatenate prefix and task name but it gives syntax error. It gives same error even I remove the prefix.

These don't work.

```
$R{task.name.$F{task_name}}
$R{"task.name."+$F{task_name}}
$R{$F{task_name}}
```

These work

```
 $R{task.name.utilLoad}
 $F{task_name}
```

I have a lot of task and the task names come from queries.I need to use loops and queries. What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used the method `str()`.

```
str("task.name."+$F{task_name}.toString())
```

Answer (score 3):

I used below syntax

Concatenate with Space
$F{USER_NAME}+" "+$F{USER_EMAIL}

Concatenate with hyphen
$F{USER_NAME}+"-"+$F{USER_EMAIL}